# I want to select an mp3 from a list and play it in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

This is both my javascript code and my html code. I cannot seem to get this to work. The player shows up, and the table shows up, and the default teaching, the one hard coded into the player plays. The problem is that when I click on the links in the table nothing happens. Please help me if possible.

Thank you in advance... BTW I am not really that proficient in javascript / jquery at all. I basically copied from somewhere else on the web, trying to make this work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<script>
    function change(sourceUrl) {
        var audio = $("player");      
        $("#mp3_src").attr("src", sourceUrl);

        /****************/
        audio[0].pause();
        audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
        audio[0].play();
        /****************/
    }
</script>


<audio id="player" controls="controls">
      <source id="mp3_src" src="/teachings/2011_01_09_Cut.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>



<table>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Date</th>
        <th align="left">Teacher</th>
        <th align="left">Topic</th>
        <th align="left">Listen</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>November 17th</td>
        <td>Pastor Bill Van Wey</td>
        <td>Prayer James Part 15</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="change('/teachings/2013_11_17_Cut.mp3');">Listen</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>November 23rd</td>
        <td>Pastor Bill Van Wey</td>
        <td>Prayer James Part 16</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="change('/teachings/2013_11_24_Cut.mp3');">Listen</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you :

**Fiddle :**  http://jsfiddle.net/rUf6j/

**HTML extract:**

```
<tr>
    <td>November 17th</td>
    <td>Pastor Bill Van Wey</td>
    <td>Prayer James Part 15</td>
    <td><a href="#" source="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Forward.mp3">Listen</a></td>
</tr>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('[source]').on('click', function(){
        change( $(this).attr('source')  );
    });

}); 

function change(sourceUrl) {
        var audio = $("player");      
        $("#mp3_src").attr("src", sourceUrl);

        /****************/
        $('audio').get(0).pause();
        $('audio').get(0).load();//suspends and restores all audio element
        $('audio').get(0).play();
    }
```

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT :**

If you want you can replace

```
<a href="#" source="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Forward.mp3">Listen</a>
```

by

```
<span source="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Forward.mp3">Listen</span>
```

`$('[source]')` ( a Jquery selector) means that it select the element which has a 'source' attribute.

So when we click a something wich has a `source` attr, it runs the `change` function.

The `change` function is called with the '`source`' in parameter.

So it replace the `src` attribute of `<audio>` tag, and restart the play.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I can see that this works on fiddle. The problem is that it doesn't appear to use any java at all to actually play the file. I don't understand how this works with only a link to the file in the anchor tag. so the # sign brings you to the top of the same page, and reloads it, and then the java fires? Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely do not need JQuery for this.  In fact it's use is probably what is messing you up right now.

Simply getting the elements by `id` and changing them through their handles will get you the same results.

```
 function change(sourceUrl) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("player"),
            source = document.getElementById("mp3_src");
    source.src = sourceUrl;
    audio.pause();
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
 }
```

**Edit**

As Paul said in the comments, yes, you do not need JQuery if you go this route.  There is a whole family of functions that let you search for elements in the DOM including `getElementById()` and they are available in almost all browsers.  For most, since they were released.  For IE, since 5.5 [MDN getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).

Don't get me wrong, I find JQuery extremely useful for both large and small scale projects that will need to span many browser types, both old and new.  That's its beauty, it handles all the idiosyncrasies for you.  For example, it wraps how you add event listeners to elements which can vary since IE used `attachEvent` rather than `addEventListener` up to IE 8.  But you don't have to include an entire library just do to simple things like searching for elements in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, this worked absolutely wonderfully. I didn't have to change anything but that little bit of java. My question is, I thought GetElementById was a function of jquery? I guess I'm just a little confused about that. Does that also mean I don't have to include the jquery reference. Is it just straight javascript?

Comment: "I didn't have to change anything but that little bit of java" Java*Script*. Java is a different language. "I thought GetElementById was a function of jquery?" Nope. "Does that also mean I don't have to include the jquery reference" Yep.

Comment: So helpful, I have been beating my head against the desk for a while trying to figure all this out. I now understand both processes / solutions and am somewhat confident on how to use them. Thank you all for the help.